# How to insert data from xml to mysql using LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to insert data from xml to mysql database using LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE  in php but it inserted blank values for self closed xml tags like `<Password />` 
 here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <Users>
        <User>
            <Password />
            <Name>name1</Name>
        </User>
    </Users>
```

php mysql code: 
`LOAD XML LOCAL FILE 'users.xml' INTO TABLE data users ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<User>';` 
how can i insert the name into the database? (this is the sample xml and i have xml with more than 9000 rows).

Comment: I got the answer, added code : $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->load($xml_file_name);
            $doc->save ( $xml_file_name, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG );       // code to remove empty records or self closed tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer 
 
`$doc = new DOMDocument();`
 `$doc->load($xml_file_name); //load xml file $xml_file_name='xml file name'`
 `$doc->save ( $xml_file_name, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG );       // code to remove empty records or self closed tag`